# Laravel 5.5 correct way for a CRUD form select

Tags: php, forms, laravel, laravel-5.5, laravel-blade

So I have this CRUD where I use the same form to create and edit entries.
I need in several form selects, when creating (no data present for that particular field yet) my select to show the placeholder, but when editing, my select to show whatever is stored on database for that particular id filed. So I have:
Controller:

```
...
 public function create()
    {
        $house = houses::pluck('name', 'id');
        //$thisclient = null;
        $clients = client::pluck('last_name', 'id');
        $reps = user::where('role_id', 5)->orderBy('first_name')->get()->pluck('full_name', 'id');

        return view('prospects.create', compact('house', 'clients', 'reps'));
    }

...

public function edit($id)
    {
        $house = houses::pluck('name', 'id');
        //$thisclient = user::whereId($id)->first();
        $clients = client::pluck('last_name', 'id');
        $reps = user::where('role_id', 5)->orderBy('first_name')->get()->pluck('full_name', 'id');

        $prospect = Prospect::findOrFail($id);

        return view('prospects.edit', compact('prospect', 'house', 'clients', 'reps'));
    }
```

and my view form:
Working for create:

```
{!!Form::select('client_id', $clients, null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Please Select'] ) !!}
```

Working for edit:

```
{!! Form::select('client_id', $clients, $prospect->client_id, ['class' => 'form-control'] ) !!}
```

I'm having 2 troubles here, if I have `null` as my selected field, it won't bring the selected data on `edit`, if I have `$prospect->client_id` , it will return a error on `create` as there's no data yet.
I tried to solve this by creating a variable $thishouse on controller and passing it to view on return `view('prospects.create', compact('house', 'thisclient','clients', 'reps'));` and view `Form::select('client_id', $clients, $thisclient, ['class' => 'form-control'] ) !!}` but seems a bit dirty whne having several form selects...

The second trouble is if I leave a placeholder on Edit, it will show the placeholder, not `$prospect->client_id` itself.

What's the best and simplest way to achieve all of this and use the same form for create and edit?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Form::open and Form::model to create and edit. As an example, you can set in your view:

```
@if(isset($prospect))
    {!! Form::model($prospect, ['action' => ['ProspectController@update', $prospect->id], 'method' => 'patch']) !!}
@else
    {!! Form::open(array('action' => 'ProspectController@store', 'method' => 'POST')) !!}
@endif
```

And then you can create the select like this:

```
{!! Form::select('client_id', $clients, old('client_id'), ['class' => 'form-control'] ) !!}
```

So, when you are editing, Laravel will select the attribute from the variable on model function.

And since you are using Laravel 5.5, you could also use `@isset` instruction.

Comment: Thanks Laerte . Will try it out tonight and let u know how it goes. But seems like what I was looking for

Comment: Ok! I used this code several times and works fine for me. If you have any questions just tell me!

Comment: And I see now that you are creating two view files `create` and `edit`. With this code you can create only one file for both, most of the times.